# Shooting whilst driving in FC3

Tags: far-cry-3

Is it possible to get a mod for FC3 that enables you to shoot a pistol while steering the vehicle? Say for a car chase or just to screw with Civies and Rakyat?

Comment: It definitely is possible, just like how any other mods are possible but as of right now, I am unable to find any mod like that. You could always make one yourself (if you know how). Or request for a mod like that to be made